# Can I make a WinForms OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog not yield the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, callback, dispatcher

I have a WinForms program which downloads then converts a collection of files each on their own thread via a batch thread used to report overall progress and job completion.  Each file will be downloaded on its own thread, then once downloaded, it will be passed over to its own conversion thread via a second batch thread via the main thread.  The reason for this pass-over via the main thread is so that the main thread can prompt the user for a save location for the converted version of all of these files once the first one has been downloaded.

The problem I am having is that the OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() method (which is used to obtain a save directory from the user) blocks the main thread callback from the first completed download thread.  This in turn allows other download thread to complete (not a problem) but then also begin executing their callbacks to the main thread at which point they all hit OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() which they otherwise wouldn't have done as my second batch thread would be running with the first conversion and they would be able to be added to the batch thread manager as a result of this.

I am using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(myCallbackDelegate, DispatcherPriority.Normal, myParameter) in order to make the callback to the Main Thread upon item work completion.  I have created a simplified example below to demonstrate the problem code.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    private readonly Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    //An instance of my own BatchBackgroundWorkerThread<T> class; this class parrarlelizes tasks and can report their individual and overall progress, completion and cancellation.
    private readonly BatchBackgroundWorkerThread<int> conversionBatchBackgroundWorker = new BatchBackgroundWorkerThread<int>();

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < 4; threadIndex++)
        {
            new Thread(DoSomeBackgroundWork).Start(threadIndex);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void DoSomeBackgroundWork(object threadIndex)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WorkCompletedCallback), DispatcherPriority.Normal, threadIndex);
    }

    private void WorkCompletedCallback(object threadIndex)
    {
        //Waits for CanQueueNewItems to be in a valid readable state.
        conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.WaitForPendingRun();

        //CanQueueNewItems is true when the batch background worker's batch thread has been launched and its internal CountdownEvent and cancellationState have been initialized.
        if (conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.IsBusy && conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.CanQueueNewItems)
            //Queues the item in the BatchBackgroundWorker for parrarelization with any other items.
            //NOTE: This code is not currently hit unless the user makes a dialog selection before another callback can reach the above if statement.
            conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.Additem(threadIndex);
        else
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

            conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new int[] { (int)threadIndex }, FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the DispatcherPriority to DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle - this made all the pending ShowDialog dialogs appear before having to click "OK" or "Cancel" to each one but aside that the result was still the same.

Is there a way I can stop ShowDialog from allowing other pending callbacks to the main thread from executing?

**Update:**
I've modified the code above to closer reflect what is happening in my real application.  All callback operations need to be enqueued into a BatchBackgroundWorker class I have created in order to perform their related conversions.  This is why I cannot simply set a variable before ShowDialog() is called saying that it was called since the remaining callbacks would then try to enqueue themselves into a BatchBackgroundWorker which currently has not been launched (the BatchBackgroundWorker thread is not running at this point as the launch is pending on the user's response to the dialog).

Comment: Technically, blocking the current thread is what makes a dialog box a dialog box, but I can see your reasoning for this.

Comment: @PCLuddite The particular dialog implementation is 'blocking' (as in subsequent code within the same function does not execute) but the process is *still* dispatching (handling) events, just within a dialog-owned loop, which is how the UI still functions. The problem the OP has is related to such.

Comment: @user2864740 Didn't say it wasn't.

Comment: Anyway to the main question: *no*, if the event processing was entirely suppressed the UI (of the dialog itself) would fail to function. I would really hate to 'suggest' going down the route of message interception as that just complicates the problem/issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply invert the statements, so that the flag is set before the dialog is opened.

```
wasDialogShown = true;
OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

You also should lock the code part working with `wasDialogShown`:

```
private readonly object dialogLock = new Object();

private void WorkCompletedCallback(object threadIndex)
{
    bool wasShown;
    lock(dialogLock) {
        wasShown = wasDialogShown;
        wasDialogShown = true;
    }
    if (wasShown) {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    } else {
        OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

The [Lock Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) prevents that another thread reads `wasDialogShown` after you have read it but before you have set it to `true`.

---

**Update** (in response to your update)

The solution could be to have 2 state variables: `dialogLaunched` and `conversionWorkerLaunched`. The first returning task launches the dialog. This task and tasks completing after the dialog was launched but before the conversion worker was launched are added to a queue. When the dialog closes the conversion is started and all the queued tasks are added to it. Tasks returning after the conversion was launched are added to the worker immediately.

Comment: Apologies - I oversimplified my code to try to make the problem clear but as a result partially hid it!  wasDialogShown is not actually a variable in my application as "Success" depends upon the running of a BatchBackgroundWorker<T> class I have created and initially launched after the call to ShowDialog().  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah I see, so is what you're saying: since ShowDialog() is a blocking operation, make all subsequent callbacks also block until they detect conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.CanQueueNewItems is true?  If my understanding is correct, then what is the best way to make them block?  The first thing that comes to mind is: `while (!conversionBatchBackgroundWorker.CanQueueNewItems) { }` - but I understand that this may not be best practice...

Comment: I have tried a `while (dialogLaunched) { }` polling loop and alternatively a `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()` approach.  Unfortunately because this is all happening on the main thread, approach #2 fails as it sends the whole thread to sleep and approach #1 fails because it loops infinitely and which apparently never allows what I assume is the Windows Message Loop to re-allocate time to actually show the first dialog to the user!  I'm thinking that the subsequent callbacks which enter the infinite loop instead need to be queued in some sort of 'pendingForConversionQueue'.  I'll report my findings.

Comment: Another idea is to delegate the coordination to a background thread as well. This one would then launch the worker threads. The UI-thread (main thread) would only launch the coordination thread. This way, the dialogs would not block the coordination any more.